# Rails: show.modal on a index.each form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have and index page showing a list of users. What I want is for when I click on a link_to show a certain user in that @users.each form, that shows up the modal *(pop ups fine)* but gives the data of that user in it as well.

users/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user.name, user, { remote: true, "data-target": "#modal-full" } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= render 'layouts/modalfull' %>
```

layouts/_modalfull.html.erb

```
<div id="modal-full">
  <h1 class="name"></h1>
</div>
```

UsersController

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  redirect_to do |format|
    format.js // because that would be where the js code would be to push the data to the modal, right?
  end
end
```

Now how it should go in the in the show.js.erb, I have no idea, I'm really not familiar with those stuffs, still new with Rails.

So right now, what I did, will pop-up the modal but wouldn't send the data from the user I clicked on. And I believe that's on the JavaScript side > show.js.erb.

Answer (score 0):

Continued trying different things and came up with this, which made it work.

Which is partially an answer, you'll know why bellow.

users/show.js.erb

```
$("#modal-full .name").html("<%= @user.name %>");
```

But if there is any cleaner way to do this, please share.

Because right now, the thing works, it replaces the name but, we see the change being made. So if I clicked on a John, modal would pop up with "John" written on it. Then I close it and click on "Jennifer", modal will pop up with "John" and takes a second to change it to "Jennifer".